# Is SQL equal test fast for large numbers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, performance

I run the very same query on two almost identical database. The only difference is that the first database has ID entries from 1 to 9000 for 2 tables while the other is in the 458231044 and 103511044 range for the 2 same tables. (for the same 9000 entries)

The query compares ID and UNIX time numerous times.

Running it on first database takes barely noticeable time. On the second, it takes 30s at the very least.

Is there a chance the problem is caused by the large numbers comparison? If so, how do you fix it? Would comparing string be faster?

Comment: I'd be more inclined to think it was a problem with the columns not being indexed properly on the second database, although even then that seems like a really long time to compare 9000 rows.

Comment: If it's a cartesian join, that's 81,000,000 comparisons. 30s would be a reasonable time for that kind of comparison load on a modern-ish system. So, yeah, most likely a missing index.

Comment: How do I verify and fix a missing index problem?

Comment: Also suspect missing index. Look here http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html under "Querying the database schema" and the .indicies command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would need more details or maybe some sample schemas to test with, but it sounds more like a (lack of) indexing problem than a data type problem.

Check that you have the same indexes on both databases.

Comment: Blargh, it was a missing index problem alright.

Both databases were identical, except for a UNIQUE statement I missed in the second somehow. Now I feel stupid. At least it was an easy fix.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to test this would be to just try this:

```
SELECT (1 = 1);
SELECT (9000 = 9000);
SELECT (1234567890 = 1234567890);
```

If the last one is slower its a comparison issue.

I suspect its not the numeric comparison but rather a side effect of a large primary key or a vaccuum-like operation needing to be performed. Do the other two tables have ranges that high because they were populated and later had rows deleted or did they actually start with PKs that large?

Comment: The others table started with large PK. No rows are deleted or whatsoever.

I can't really figure out if any of these 3 tests are slower, they all take so little time.

Comment: You may have to run each query individually. Either the client or your logs should show the time.  Another test to try would be to create a simple table, two columns, just an integer PK and a string. Populate it with 1000 rows with PKs from 1-1000, see how long a SELECT takes. DELETE those rows, and populate it from 10000-20000, repeat. 

I really think theres some SQLite quirk with large tables or maybe a missing index.

Answer (score 0):

It may be the datatype being used for that particular index.  It makes sense that if its a larger datatype that comparisons may take longer.

Another possibility is that the second database isn't set up for indexing the same way the first database is.